# How do I remove CAShapeLayer from UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm creating audio recording app just like Voice Memo. So far I'm able to record, play, trim and merge the audio. I create timeline of  wave bars just like bar visualisation in any music app.

When user stops recording, he can go back to particular second to record it again from there if he makes mistake. For example, if he stops recording at 50 seconds because he made a mistake after 45 seconds. He will go to 45 seconds by dragging horizontal scrollbar(timeline). And when he taps record button, I want to clear all wave bars after 45 seconds. How do I achieve this? This is how I'm creating wave bars in scrollview using `CAShapeLayer`.

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[shapeLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, barWidth, barHeight) cornerRadius:2] CGPath]];
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.position = CGPointMake(barX, scrlViewBars.frame.size.height - barHeight);
[scrlViewBars.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

This code is written in a loop which will be called 2 times every second after recording starts. Thus creates wave bars. So how do I remove the layer added to `UIScrollView`. I found that nilling `layer.sublayers` will remove the layer. But I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to first create a `NSMutableArray` of pointers to `CAShapeLayer`s  that you are adding.

Then call adding layer to that array somewhat like this:

```
...
shapeLayer.position = CGPointMake(barX, scrlViewBars.frame.size.height - barHeight);
[addedLayers addObject:shapeLayer];
[scrlViewBars.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

I'm assuming `barX` is some sort of number, probably a `CGFloat` and is incrementing by the same constant every 30 seconds. Now you need to find a formula to transform `barX` into index of layer added at that `barX`.

Say you are adding layers every 30px of X axis, that would mean

```
barX 0 --> index 0
barX 30 --> index 1
barX 60 --> index 2
...
```

You should know what is the `barX` at 45 seconds and calculate the index of `addedLayers` at that point of time, let's name it `index`.

Now after user tapped at 45 seconds you run a loop:

```
for(int i = index; i < addedLayers.count; i++){
    [[addedLayers objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

What it did is it removed all layers from 45 seconds onwards.
Now after that you have to remove them from the array so run

```
 [addedLayers removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(index, [addedLayers count] - index)];
```

That's the way I would do it, let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks fo ther reply. That looks promising. I hope it will work. I will let you know after implementing

Comment: @HirenPrajapati did it work or have you encountered any issue?

Comment: it worked like a charm. Per second I'm creating two wave bars. So it was too easy after your hint. Thank you. Upvoting answer